# How to change decimal separator in velocity template?

Tags: java, decimal, velocity

I have a vlt template as follows:

```
$display.printf("Total: %4.2f s", $toto.tata)
```

Which display :

```
Total: 11.2 s
```

But I want to display it with a comma separator for the decimal number:

```
Total: 11,2 s
```

How can I change the decimal format ?

I cannot change the JAVA code..

Thanks for your help

Comment: https://velocity.apache.org/tools/3.0/tools-summary.html - For instance `$config.locale="fr_FR"`. BTW `display.message` should also take care of thousands separators.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the Java class of the `$display` object, but it's the object in question which formats the number, not Velocity itself, so if this object doesn't offer the ability to specify a locale (as do `String.format()` and `PrintWriter.printf()`), you will have to resort of some hack, like:

```
$display.printf("Total: %4.2f s", $toto.tata).replace('.',',')
```